# Module Loads In Django Shell/Dev But Issues In Prod

Tags: python, django

I have a module that's loaded in my app, when I do a `python manage.py shell`, I can load and work with it fine, as well as a `runserver`, it all works great. However, when I try to load it in a view on a production server, I cant seem to get it work. I get a "cannot import name pywraplp".  I have ran out of ideas and looking for some advice on what else I can do to try to get this to work.

I'm running nginx, gunicorn, and uwsgi

Comment: Have you tried to install the module on the server or virtual environment in the server?

Comment: yes thats all I have been doing